# Unable to find the fragment by tag when Back Button is pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, back

I have two fragments namely `FoodFragment` and `WishlistFragment` these two are opened when i press their respective item clicks through the `NavigationView`

The problem I'm facing is when I press on the navigation items the fragments corresponding to them opens and everything works fine but when i press the back button, the MainActivity's `onBackPressed()` method is called and it only works for the first condition on the fragment that I've written.

Here's my code:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        mFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (id == R.id.food) {

            if(newFragment == null) {
                newFragment = FoodFragment.newInstance("food", "fragment");
                mFragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.appBar, newFragment, "FoodFragment").addToBackStack("FoodFragment").commit();
            }

        }else if(id == R.id.wishlist){
            if(wishFragment == null){
                wishFragment = WishlistFragment.newInstance("wish", "fragment");
                mFragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.appBar, wishFragment, "WishFragment").addToBackStack("WishFragment").commit();
            }
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Here's the onBackPressed() method:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        try {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }  else if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("WishFragment").isVisible()){
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                wishFragment = null;
            }else if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FoodFragment").isVisible()) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                newFragment = null;
            }else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException npe){
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

I've added tags to each fragment as you can see in the code and handling them through the `onBackPressed()` method. Here, when I open the `WishFragment` and press back button everything is cleared and so i can open the `WishFragment` again by pressing the Navigation Item corresponding to it. But, this seems to be getting wrong in case of `FoodFragment` when I open the fragment and press back button, the condition corresponding to it is not executed and So, I'm unable to open the `FoodFragment` again.

But, if I change the ordering of conditions in `onBackPressed()` like this:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        try {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }else if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FoodFragment").isVisible()) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                newFragment = null;
            }  else if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("WishFragment").isVisible()){
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                wishFragment = null;
            }else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException npe){
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

It seems to work now with `FoodFragment` but not with `WishFragment`, as a result I was able to open the `FoodFragment` again but not the `WishFragment`. I've searched for this problem on many websites but, I cannot get the right answer.

I've resolved it by adding `view.setOnKeyListener(//calling the MainActivity by KeyEvents)` for the fragment but, this doesn't seem to be a good way to do things as it reloads my entire `MainActivity` again.

I don't know where I'm doing wrong. Please suggest me a better way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When the `WishFragment` is open and you press the back button

`getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FoodFragment").isVisible()`

This throws a NullPointerException.

So it will always do `super.onBackPressed()`since you are catching all the `NullPointerException`

To solve this change your if else statement to

```
if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
} else if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FoodFragment") != null && getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FoodFragment").isVisible()) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    newFragment = null;
} else if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("WishFragment") != null && getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("WishFragment").isVisible()){
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    wishFragment = null;
} else { 
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```